# How to trigger CSS when a cursor is within a specific pixel distance of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I would like to know if there is a performant way of triggering a CSS animation when a cursor is near an HTML element. For example, Squarespace animates a marker at the bottom of each box when you get within a certain distance of each corner of the container:

[image: Proximity animations]

Notice how the cursor appears at the corner when I get a certain distance away, regardless of which direction my cursor comes from? This leads me to believe it is not just a simple `.parent-container:hover > .child-element` CSS style. It must be with Javascript.

I've discovered you can recreate this behavior by attaching a `mousemove` event listener on each element you want to animate by tracking the difference between mouse position and element position like this:

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
mousemoveFn(ev: MouseEvent) {

 // perform code to calculate distance between cursor position and
 // the element the listener is attached to
 // returns a boolean if the cursor is "near by" element or not

}
```

This code was taken from this [npm Angular directive](https://github.com/mskasal/ngx-nearby/blob/master/projects/ngx-nearby/src/lib/ngx-nearby.directive.ts)

The issue is that I need to have several of these proximity animation events on my page, and I am already seeing massive performance hits with 10 `mousemove` event listeners that trigger on every `requestAnimationFrame()`. So obviously this is not the best route.

Does anyone have suggestions of a more performant / elegant solution that would accomplish similar CSS animation behavior?

---

EDIT

I figured they were using JS to trigger the animation because I tracked the movement using the `Performance` tab on Chrome, and saw the following `mousemove` event handler, except it appears that there are WAY less calls to the `mousemove` event compared to my implementation. Is there a global mousemove listener maybe?

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the page? Should be pretty simple to reverse engineer what's going on. To me, this looks like a simple hide/show when the cursor enters the bounds of the corner (which likely has an invisible element extending outwards from the corner)

Comment: @TimLewis I went through each parent `div` and added the `:hover` pseudo element from the chrome inspector and none of them triggered the animation. I'm normally pretty good at reverse engineering these types of things but this one has me stumped

Comment: Also, when I track event listeners on the `Performance` tab of chrome I can observe `mousemove` events on the Squarespace page, but it seems like there is only a single global mousemove listener because their event queue is MUCH less packed than mine

Answer (score 1):

Using a wrapper on this element with a padding is probably what is used in your example. Here is a simple example to get the idea:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

div:hover p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, there doesn't appear to be any parent padding around the element via the inspector. I've added an edit to explain why I think they are using JS @johannchopin